# Can't connect Docker CLI to local Docker Daemon

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm, minikube

I downloaded minikube after that ...

1. I did `minikube start`... so, node started
2. I played around with some containers(deployment object)
3. Now when I am doing `docker ps` => it's showing all the k8's container running  -_-"

**What I wanted to see is the local Docker Daemon containers rather than Vm's containers**

---

When I run  `minikube docker-env`  it shows:

> Exiting due to ENV_DRIVER_CONFLICT: 'none' driver does not support 'minikube docker-env' command

**What should I do now to connect to local Docker Daemon ?**

*I am using Ubuntu 18* :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you started minikube without specifying driver, the host docker daemon will be used, so you can access it without any special environment variables. That’s why you see “ *Exiting due to ENV_DRIVER_CONFLICT: 'none' driver does not support 'minikube docker-env' command*”

Try starting minikube using other driver viz `minikube start --driver=hyperkit`
or stopping minkikube

Comment: minikube start --driver=hyperkit

Comment: Which driver you are using depends on which OS you are using ! ~~~~~~ To use a different driver, delete your cluster: ~~~~~~

>minikube delete ~~~~~~

RESTART with a different driver: ~~~~~~

MACOS: ~~~~~~

>minikube start --driver=hyperkit ~~~~~~

OR ~~~~~~

>minikube start --driver=virtualbox ~~~~~~

WINDOWS: ~~~~~~

>minikube start --driver=hyperv ~~~~~~

OR ~~~~~~

>minikube start --driver=virtualbox :)